# Devise + associated Profile model - show profile page returning error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

static page with link

```
<h1>Dashboard</h1>
<%= link_to 'Dashboard', :action => :dashboard %> |
<%= link_to 'Ask for help', :controller => :tasks, :action => :new %> |
<%= link_to 'Profile', profile_path %>| #relevant line
```

profiles controller

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @profile = Profile.new
    end

    def create
         @profile = Profile.new(params[:profile])
         @profile.user_id = current_user.id
         if @profile.save
             redirect_to static_pages_dashboard_path
         end
    end

    def edit
        @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
    end

    def show
        @profile = Profile.current_user
    end
end
```

routes.rb

```
 Test::Application.routes.draw do
      get "welcome/index"
      get "static_pages/home"
      get "static_pages/dashboard"
      get "tasks/index"

      root "static_pages#home"
      devise_for :users 
      resources :tasks
      resources :profiles
 end
```

I'm trying to make a separate model/controller to handle user's personal info, called `profile`.

Trying to link to the `show` action/view from Dashboard view results in the error:
**ActionController::UrlGenerationError in StaticPages#dashboard

No route matches {:controller=>"profiles", :action=>"show"} missing required keys: [:id]**
How do I fix this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass profile id to make profile show url generation possible (otherwise, Rails don't know which profile you want to link to):

```
<%= link_to 'Profile', profile_path(current_user.profile) %>
```

Of course, you need to make sure that the associations are set and that the user always has associated profile. Or, you could check for profile existence before rendering link, like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Profile', profile_path(current_user.profile) if current_user.profile %>
```

Comment: Hi I just tried as you suggested but still got an error - `No route matches {:id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]` @marek

Comment: @jenkhai it's because your `current_user` doesn't have it's associated profile. Please check out my edited answer.